# Cmake で外部ライブラリを指定する方法を教えてください

Tags: c++, cmake

#### 環境

C++ 20
CLion
Cmake 3.16

#### 質問

GitHub で公開されている [MinHook](https://github.com/TsudaKageyu/minhook) というライブラリの DLL を使いたいのですが、Cmake を使ってビルドする方法がわかりません。

僕のプロジェクトはこのようなディレクトリ構造になっています。
プロジェクト名はTestです。

```
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
Dependencies
         |--- Minhook
                   |--- bin
                          |--- MinHook.x86.dll
                          |--- MinHook.x86.lib
                   |--- include
                          |--- MinHook.h
```

#### 現在のCMakeList.txt とエラー内容

色々調べてそれっぽく書いたのですが、動きませんでした。
追記:ご指摘いただいて書き換えた後のスクリプトとエラー文に変えました。

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories("D:/Dev/Cpp/Test/Dependencies/Minhook/include")

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Test D:/Dev/Cpp/Test/Dependencies/Minhook/bin/MinHook.x86.lib)
```

今度は識別子がどうとかと言われています。
これは僕がmain.cpp内で定義した関数ポインタなどが問題と言われています。MinHook.hがインクルードされていないのが原因だと思います(下画像参照)。このコード自体はVisual Studioで動くことを確認済みですのでコードは間違っていません。

```
D:\Dev\Cpp\Test\main.cpp(19): error C3861: 'originalTest': 識別子が見つかりませんでした
D:\Dev\Cpp\Test\main.cpp(30): error C2065: 'shellcodePtr': 定義されていない識別子です。
D:\Dev\Cpp\Test\main.cpp(36): error C2065: 'shellcodePtr': 定義されていない識別子です。
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~2\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1426~1.288\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe' : リターン コード '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : リターン コード '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : リターン コード '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"' : リターン コード '0x2'
Stop.
```

画像の通り `Minhook.h is not found` となっています。

[image: 読み込めていない]

Comment: `include_directories` に指定するのは **ディレクトリ(フォルダ)名** じゃないでしょうか。今現在指定しているのはファイル名になっているように見えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！修正したのですがまたエラーが発生したので、編集して載せておきます！

Comment: ごめんなさい、#include "Dependencies/Minhook/include/MinHook.h"に変えたところうまくいきました！！！ありがとうございます

Comment: ヒントになったようで何よりです。解決したようであればぜひ [自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) の形で投稿してみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました
cubicさんありがとうございました

コメントにあるとおり、

```
#include "Dependencies/Minhook/include/MinHook.h"
```

に変えたところうまくいきました！